# jQuery function to open 2 connected, draggable images on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to programming and it should be easy, however I can't understand how to do it. I need create 2 images on one button click, one image is main, another is like close X button. They must be connected and draggable.

This is my function: [Js Fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/ElecTed/jv89bmLt/)

```
<input type="button" id="truck" class="truckbtn" value="ADD Truck" onclick="addtruck()">
<div id="masina">
    <div id="closebutton"></div>
    <div id="truckshow"></div>
</div>

<Script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".truckbtn").click(function() {
            var truckshow = $('<img height="200" width="100" src="images/Truck1.png">');
            var closebutton = $('<img height="50" width="50" src="images/closeimage2.png">');
            $('div').prepend(truckshow + closebutton);
            truckshow.draggable();
            closebutton.draggable();
        });
    });
</Script>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Here I have a sample code ([JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zzLpy988/1/)) using `draggable()` of [Jquery UI](https://jqueryui.com/draggable/) for dragging components inside DOM. 
My buttons style are from [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/), you can also write custom CSS although I used a framework for saving time.

**EDITS**

Image is dynamically added  on button click.
You can change image dynamically by changing src of `<img/>` tag using jquery.
let `<img id="myImage"/> then you can set src by $("#myImage").attr("src","your link here");`.

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/zzLpy988/3/)

Comment: ty, however i am looking to creat image from button click , that is dragabble and have close button

Comment: @AleksandrL try above code and see if it suits your need. [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/zzLpy988/4/)

Comment: yeah its look good, now i need with each press +1 more image :)